# Angular active class on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular app I have three buttons, each representing a different state.

```
<ul class="handset-qty-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{'active': devices.length < 5 && tariffTypeSelection !== 'welcome'}">1 - 4 {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
    <li ng-class="{'active': devices.length >= 5}">5 - 19 {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
    <li>20 + {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
</ul>
```

The current rule for the tabs becoming active is based on the `length` of `devices`. In addition to this though I want the buttons to be clickable and onclick, the clicked tab has the active class. There should only be one active class at one time between all three buttons.

Pretty standard, simple stuff but what's the best-practise Angular way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in angular way you need to keep which tab is currently active and find a way to switch it with a function so the default value for the active tab and the function definition should be

```
scope.activeTab = scope.devices.length < 5 && scope.tariffTypeSelection !== 'welcome' ? "first" : "second"; // only have first and second just implement the others.

//will bind this to the ng-click
scope.tabClick = function(tab) {
   scope.activeTab = tab;
};
```

the controller logic is ready now for the view;

```
<ul class="handset-qty-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 'first' }" ng-click="tabClick('first');">1 - 4 {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
    <li ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 'second'" ng-click="tabClick('second');">5 - 19 {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
    <li>20 + {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
</ul>
```

this is really simple example of course if you can (or if you already have) build a tab array like below;

```
scope.tabs = [{text: "1 - 4", isActive: true}, {text: "5 - 19", isActive: false}];
//don t forget to set isActive accroding to your rule also build texts properly
scope.tabClick = function(index) {
   angular.forEach(scope.tabs, function(t){t.isActive = false;});
   scope.tabs[index].isActive = true;
};
```

and similar to above example set the display and click with ng-repeat;

```
<ul class="handset-qty-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{'active': tab.isActive }" ng-click="tabClick($index);">{{tab.text}} {{ params.device_name }}s</li>
</ul>
```

the second one is the actual angular way just started with the first one for a easy transition.

Hope helps.

Comment: It's a shame that such a thing can be achieved with 2 small lines of jQuery but I don't want to start mixing the two!

Comment: that s true also not fair to angular to compare it with a simple example. when you have more complex data and structure you will see.

Comment: using the second one that you've described as the 'actual angular way', how do I add a count in there so that if `devices.length > 5` "1-4" tab is active, if `devices.length >= 5` "5-19" tab is active?

Comment: you need to set isActive property while building tabs array.